# issue with multer not allowing a default image

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

So I am having an issue with multer that i can't figure out. When I add an item with an image everything works with no issues but if I try to add an item with no image it fails.  I have an if statement that will define a default image if req.file is undefined but it fails with the error saying req.file.filename is undefined ...  Here is the code

Multer setup:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, "./public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + file.originalname);
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("file");
```

route:

```
router.post("/item/add", middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  User.findById(req.user._id, (err, user) => {
    upload(req, res, err => {
      if (err) {
        req.flash("error", "failed to upload file");
        return res.redirect("/products");
      }
      var item = new Item();
      item.name = req.body.name;
      item.description = req.body.description;
      item.price = req.body.price;
      item.createdBy = { id: req.user._id, username: req.user.username };
      if (typeof req.file === undefined) {
        item.image = "/uploads/no-img.png";
      } else {
        item.image = "/uploads/" + req.file.filename;
      }
      item.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          res.send(err);
        }
        return res.redirect("/products");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

So I guess my question is... How would I set this up where it wont fail with no image selected?

Comment: Should that not be `req.files`? Maybe it accepts both. Since the name "multer" is derived from "mutipart content" then I would presume the naming to be "plural". As a basic debugging tip you probably should `console.log(req)` or `console.log(JSON.stringify(req, undefined,2))` or similar to actually inspect the content before jumping to conclusions. That should be your first step anyway. And I think it's `path` and not `filename` at any rate.

Comment: @NeilLunn Nope, [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) say that `req.file` is applicable here. Also, `filename` is correct. Note that OP says everything works fine when they do pass an image.

Comment: Show the `console.log` output. But then again I just spotted an answer added and was not paying attention to the `typeof` myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

`if (typeof req.file === undefined) {`

[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns a string.

Your check should be `if (typeof req.file === "undefined") {`

Comment: Man, I completely overlooked that ... Noob mistake but thank you so much.